# How to upload a package to private universe (without rebuilding it)?

Tags: dcos

I have DCOS running in a network without Internet access. I cannot copy files from an internet connected machine to the isolated network. There is a local universe running in DCOS.

Is it possible to upload a package to the local universe without having to rebuild the universe completely (with all existing packages) and if so, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible yet. You'll have to rebuild the private Universe.